# iOS 14 widget not found after updating the app

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit

I have a widget app on production.
There are 5 static widgets.
For example, in the new release, I added another new widget. After updating the app new widget not found in the widget container.

Does anyone face this problem?

Comment: Try restarting the device. iOS seems to occasionally “lose” widgets after app updates but a restart fixes it.

Comment: I tried with it. But did not find my new widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your updated app. After this your widgets should appear in widgets list